# Reporting policy effect for specific subpopulation - how to interract?

Tags: inference, interaction, model-selection, causality

I am seeking guidance on model selection when reporting a causal policy effect for a specific subgroup of the panel. I am open to any form of help: paper, maths, intuitions... Below my setup, please feel free to point out to any flaws.

- I use panel data of N individuals and T years.
- My dependent variable is $Y_{it}$ and I am interested in causal inference for a binary policy variable $D_{it}$. Conditional on control variables, $D_{it}$ is exogenous and random such that the estimates effect can be assumed causal.
- A priori $D_{it}$ can have an effect on the **whole population**, but I am fundamentally only interested to report the causal effect for a **subset of individuals $i$** belonging to a specific group, defined as $\{i \in  I \}$. For example it could be that $I$ corresponds to a specific town in a nationwide panel, to a specific age or education group, ethnic minority etc...
- I also impose $card(I) << N$, the number of individuals in the subgroup is significantly small compared to the number if individuals in the panel. This is not essential but basically I do not want to estimate the model using $I$ only.

With regards to the effect that I am interested to report, and omitting constant and control variables for simplicity, I consider two models:
$$
Y_{it} = \alpha_1 D_{it} + \alpha_2 D_{it}*\unicode{x1D7D9}\{i \in  I \}+\alpha_3 \unicode{x1D7D9}\{i \in  I \} + u_{it}
$$
or as an alternative
$$
Y_{it} = \beta_1 D_{it}*\unicode{x1D7D9}\{i \notin  I \} + \beta_2 D_{it}*\unicode{x1D7D9}\{i \in  I \}+\beta_3 \unicode{x1D7D9}\{i \in  I \} + v_{it}
$$
$\alpha_3$ and $\beta_3$ depict a fixed-effect of the subgroup but they are not central for my question.

The big difference between both is that I exclude the subgroup of interest from the rest of the population in the second model, while it is still included in the first model. If I choose the first model, the policy effect for the subgroup is given by $\hat{\alpha_1} + \hat{\alpha_2}$, in the second model it is given by $\hat{\beta_2}$.

In theory, this is just a linear transformation so I did not expect dramatic changes. Yet my results look something along these lines (s.e. in parenthesis). For model 1: $\hat{\alpha_1} ; \hat{\alpha_2} =  0.05(0.05);0.05(0.05)$, so both effects are insignificant. For model 2, I get a significant effect, e.g. $\hat{\beta_2} =  0.10(0.05)$.

So choosing model 1 leads me to conclude that there is no policy effect for the subgroup. Choosing model 2 leads me to conclude that there is a policy effect of 0.1 for the subgroup.